# Oauth 2 returns invalid client

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, discord, token

I tried to implement Oauth 2.0 using the Discord Api. I know there are packages that implements this for me, but I want do do this at my own. I have the following code (node JS)

```
axios
    .post(
        "https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token",
        "client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&grant_type=client_credentials&code=" + code + "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000"
```

this always results in the error "invalid client."
BUT using Postman
[image: postman screenshot]

this works!
So I dont know, what I am doing wrong in my js...

Thanks for your help.

By the Way: I am very new to nodeJs.

Comment: Did you comapre your request via postman and via code? Paste that both here

Comment: Are you trying to access service from other service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I could find my Problem:
I saved the Client ID as an Int Value, it was all numbers. Once I put '' around the client ID, it worked. Didnt knew this was a thing.

Comment: Mine is of String type but still didnt work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, try setting with proper header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
const axios = require('axios')
const qs = require('querystring')
    
const requestBody = {
  client_id: 'clientId',
  client_secret: 'CLIENT SEVRET',
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  code: 'code',
  redirect_uri: 'http://locahost:5000'
}

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}

axios.post("https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token", qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
  .then((result) => {
    // Do something
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Do something
  })
```

Comment: As stated in my previous comment, can show you request sent via postman and code?

Comment: I did, you can see both the Image of my Postman Setup and my request on JS in my Post. Or are you searching something else?

Comment: I mean actual network call snapshot or capture. What you have shown above is code for request. When that request is sent by axios what it looks like.Also  in postman there is `code` button on right hand. copy paste that

Comment: I have also update code with correct `grant_type`. please check that and replace with your own values

Comment: Code generated by Postman:

var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token',
    headers:
        {  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    form:
        { client_id: 'CLIENT ID',
            client_secret: 'CLIENT SECRET',
            code: 'CODE',
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:5000' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});

Comment: Now how your request looks when it flows through network?

Comment: Didnt work for me :(